# MySQL view converting rows to column

Tags: mysql, view

I would like to convert the row to column of mySQL.

I have a table with four field

```
Excode SyID adno Mark
IA1      1  2220  70
IA1      1  2134  75
IA1      3  2220  73
IA1      3  2134  80
IA2      1  2220  81
IA2      1  2134  79
IA2      3  2220  65
IA2      3  2134  72
.....
.....
```

The "SyID" and "adno" will remain in the column itself and The no.s of unique value in "Excode" should be increase in column as follows

```
SyID adno IA1 IA2 ..... ...... .....
1    2220  70  81 ..... ...... .....
3    2220  73  65 ..... ...... .....
1    2134  75  79 ..... ...... .....
3    2134  80  72 ..... ...... .....
.. ...... ..... .... ..... ...... .....
.. ...... ..... .... ..... ...... .....
```

Please guide me. Thanking You.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I'm not sure it is possible to do that using only MySQL. However it is possible using a programming language (maybe PHP?) after you've retrieved all values from your table or view.

Comment: How many `IA?` `Excode` values are there?

Comment: I have already created a table to inset the marks according to the adno. Now I have create marsheet of the adno. Using PHP I think it will use a lots of server resources as there are lots of records,

Comment: @HeatfanJohn It is not fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the closest you'll come to "PIVOTing" a non-fixed number of rows into a single row in MySQL is in using the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function. This won't exactly get you all of the `Excode`s into separate columns, but rather as a single delimited string:

```
SELECT   SyID, 
         adno, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Excode, ': ', Mark) SEPARATOR ' / ') AS ExcodeMarks
FROM     tbl
GROUP BY SyID, adno
```

This will produce something *similar* to what you want:

```
SyID   |   adno   |   ExcodeMarks
----------------------------------------------
1      |   2220   |   IA1: 70 / IA2: 81
3      |   2220   |   IA1: 73 / IA2: 65
1      |   2134   |   IA1: 75 / IA2: 79 
3      |   2134   |   IA1: 80 / IA2: 72
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. but I need all the mark in a separate column so as I have to find out the topper for each class, each subject, Division of the student an so on. Is there any option to create a new view of this view to get the desired column.